# second auto increment field based on foreign key in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a `Lesson` Model like this :

```
class Lesson extends Model
{
        use SoftDeletes;

        public $primaryKey = 'lesson_id';

        public function contents ()
        {
              return $this->hasMany('App\Content', 'lesson_id', 'lesson_id');
        }
}
```

And a `Content Model like this :

```
class Content extends Model
    {
        public $primaryKey = 'content_id';
        public $timestamps = false;

        public $fillable = ['lesson_id', 'order'];

        public function lesson ()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Lesson', 'lesson_id', 'lesson_id');
        }
}
```

In `Content` Model, there is an **order** column that increases after each content insertion based on `lesson_id` field like this:

```
|------|---------|---------------|
|  id  |lesson_id |     order     |
|------|---------|---------------|
|  1   |    1    |       1       |
|  2   |    1    |       2       |
|  3   |    1    |       3       |
|  4   |    2    |       1       |
|  5   |    1    |       4       |
|  6   |    1    |       5       |
|  7   |    2    |       2       |
|  8   |    3    |       1       |
|  9   |    3    |       2       |
|------|---------|---------------|
```

For that I must run below codes before each insertion query to Calculate `order` column for a specific `lesson_id`:

```
$lesson_id = $request->get('lesson_id')

$lastOrder =
    Content::whereHas('lesson', function ($query) use ($lesson_id) {
        $query->where('lesson_id', $lesson_id);
    })->max('order');


    if (is_null($lastOrder)) {
        $lastOrder = 0;
    }

    $newContent =
        Content::create(
            [
                'lesson_id' => $lesson_id,
                'order'     => $lastOrder + 1
            ]
         );
```

I want a way in laravel that this operations done on insertion new **Content** instance automatically.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: Would another object holding an array of  'order_id'   =>  'maxCouint' be useful. the method `getNextOrderCount($orderId);` would increment the appropriate count and return it?

Comment: @Ryan's suggestion is a good one to achieve what you want. However, you might think about making an entirely new table. It's hard to really see what makes sense for your system without seeing more, but to me it seems like once you're trying to keep track of so many things in one table, maybe there are separate concepts, like maybe an orders table represents the orders, and then it just has a list of lesson_ids that belong to the order. This would clean things up and as a side effect would solve your problem.